# J2ME: UI framework

Tags: java, frameworks, java-me

We are starting a fresh J2ME application development.

(example: in .NET Composite Application Block for Mobile Devices)

I could see www.j2mepolish.org is providing a UI framework.

Any other popular framework available for UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netbeans IDE has a UI deigner like swing that name is Visual Mobile Designer (VMD). see these link : 
http://wiki.netbeans.org/VisualMobileDesignerPalatteReference
http://www.javanb.com/netbeans/1/19752.html

Answer (score 3):

You can also look at [LWUIT](https://lwuit.dev.java.net/), though J2ME Polish have been around for a longer time, I think.

Comment: I am going through this library. We will learn and decide quickly. Thanks for reply. Have you used this LWUIT in your project?

Comment: I have used both LWUIT and J2ME Polish before. I personally prefer to write custom UI controls for my projects as I find them more lightweight, but if I had to choose I would pick J2ME Polish, it is more robust imho.